# Next environment variables in Flask API route

Tags: python, flask, next.js, python-venv

I've set up a Python backend for my Next frontend according to this [Vercel article](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-use-python-and-javascript-in-the-same-application).

How do I access environment variables in these Python API routes?

In development, the information is saved in `.env.local`, and in deployment they would be added in the Vercel dashboard of the project.

If this were a standard Node API route, I would access the environment variables like this:

```
const username = process.env.username
```

Near the top of this [Vercel documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables), it mentions that Python environment variables can be accessed like this:

```
username = os.environ.get('username')
```

But this doesn't work and the variable is undefined when it comes time to use it.

My guess is that this has something to do with the fact that when testing on `localhost`, the Flask server is running in a `venv` virtual environment according to this [VS Code tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask) and this [other tutorial](https://codevoweb.com/how-to-integrate-flask-framework-with-nextjs/).

The Flask server is also running on a different port than the Next frontend, so it makes sense that it would not have access to the `.env.local` file.

I'm entirely new to using a non-Node backend for my Next API routes, so I'm not too sure how to set this up correctly. There aren't too many questions/articles out there about using a Python backend for a Next frontend, and the few that I've found don't mention environment variables.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the information that will be stored in the environment variables. As far as it comes to using flask as a backend api environment variables are used for setting a database URL, SecretKey, minutes until token expiration etc. Your username example makes me think that your definition of environment variables is entirely different from the "flask/python definition".

Comment: @Lenntror For now it would be just be information used to authenticate with an API - information like my client ID and client secret. They can just be hardcoded in the API route without much worry since that runs server-side only, but if I were using standard Node API routes, I would use environment variables for this, and want to try the same here.

Comment: Ok, I do not think that this is a common usecase for environment variables in flask. I recommend this tutorial to see how user authentication can be done in flask (and how its normally done) https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask